# MySqli Fulltext Matching

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

```
SELECT DESCP, MATCH (DESCP, NAME) AGAINST ('slice' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) AS Score FROM products WHERE MATCH (DESCP, NAME) AGAINST ('slice')
```

Above is the query I have as an example.

The results I get are:

- Slice Decorated Chocolate Cake, Chocolatec 1
- Cake Slice   1
- Kraft Natural Big Slice Aged Swiss Cheese 1

  SELECT DESCP, MATCH (DESCP, NAME) AGAINST ('slices' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) AS Score FROM products WHERE MATCH (DESCP, NAME) AGAINST ('slices')

This query results in:

- CHEESE SLICES    1
- Kraft Natural Sliced Extra Thin Swiss Cheese - 8 o   1
- Sargento Ultra Thin Sliced Baby Swiss Cheese - 18    1
- Sargento Natural Deli Style   Sliced Swiss Cheese -  1
- Kraft Natural Big Slice Aged Swiss Cheese - 8   oz   1
- Sargento Sliced Muenster Natural Cheese 8 oz.    1
- Kraft Sliced Deli Deluxe American Cheese 16 Slices...    1

So my question is:

How do I match a fulltext match that will find all the words for slice, sliced, slices, etc. I am taking user input from a text box and the expectation is that if someone searched for "slice" or "slices" that they get all the correct results.

Comment: This function you're looking for is called "stemming" in the world of lex search.

Comment: Thanks now I know the term for it. The link you provided eventually leads to a bunch of 404s so it doesn't really help as much to anyone looking for a similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `LIKE`

```
SELECT * from table WHERE field LIKE '%slice%'
```

% matches any prefix/suffix

Comment: So If someone types in cheese slice SELECT * from table WHERE field LIKE '%cheese slice%' will match Kraft Natural Sliced Extra Thin Swiss Cheese?

Comment: anything with 'cheese slice' in there content will be included, include `cheese slices` or `anytextcheese sliceanytext`

Comment: I disagree in that it won't return the desired results and that I am reading fulltext is more efficient. If a person types "Cheese slice" and the record is "Sliced cheese" %cheese slice% will not result in anything. Plus it would need to be %cheese%slice% to give any sort of result at all. And then the stop words will not be omitted.

Comment: You can `explode` the users search text by spaces then concatinate a `OR LIKE` for each entry. `LIKE '%cheese slices%' OR '%slices%' OR '%cheese%'`